# Return Multiple Objects From Array Through a Method

Tags: c#, methods

The method below returns only the first object in the array.

```
public string PRINT_CRATE()
{

    foreach (var soda in sodaCans)
    {
        if (soda != null)
        {
            return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, soda);                    
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Empty spot");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

It works fine except from that I want it to "group up" all the objects and return them. As it is now, only the first object get's returned.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Look into string concatenation and/or the StringBuilder.

Comment: What is `sodaCans`?  `string[]`?  `List<string>`?

Comment: In any event, you're using `String.Join` on a single element of the collection, when in reality you just need to pass the collection into `String.Join` - `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, sodaCans);`.  [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Final comment - it returns the first object because you tell it to.   `return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, soda);` will exit the method the first time a non-null element is found.   The next time you enter the method, it will start over.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to return a single string with all the data put into it, you are probably looking for something like that:

```
public string PrintCrate()
{
    string rv = "";
    foreach (var soda in sodaCans)
    {
        if (soda != null)
        {
            rv += "\n" + soda;                    
        }
    }

    return rv;
}
```

EDIT: According to the comments, my solution was sub-optimal.

I'd like to point out, that [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362181/4922365) is probably the best solution. It is short, correctly handles the newlines, and outputs the `"Empty Spot"` entries as the OP has probably wanted.

Out of educational value, I'll include a version with `StringBuilder` and manual enumeration that is comparable with Erik's answer in that it is close to the implementation of `string.Join()`:

```
public string PrintCrate()
{
    using (var enumerator = sodaCans.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return null
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append(enumerator.Current ?? "EmptySpot");
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            stringBuilder.Append(enumerator.Current ?? "EmptySpot");
        }
        return StringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `String.Join` or even `StringBuilder` would be better than `+=`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's so obvious when I see it. But yet I'm till too fresh to figure it out. Thanks again mate =)

Comment: @Tim For someone who starts with this kind of coding, I think it is more comprehensible to use simple strings. And besides, I'm pretty sure the compiler or jit will use the StringBuilder behind the scenes, on such obvious cases.

Comment: @justme no, the compiler/jit will not rewrite your code to use a stringbuilder. Also note that your code puts a newline at the start of the string, where string.join wouldn't.

Comment: @justme - Given that OP had `String.Join` in their question, I think it would have been better to show them how to *properly* use it to achieve the results they wanted, along with an explanation as to why `String.Join` or `StringBuilder` would be a better choice than `+=`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest thing to do what you're asking for is a Linq query:

```
return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sodaCans.Select(x => x ?? "EmptySpot"));
```

The `.Select` method allows you to transform each element, and here I'm using the null coalescing operator `??` to replace null values with `"EmptySpot"`.